# gulp install error

Tags: docker

```
caner@vegan:~/hb-productupload/gateway$ gulp install
[14:28:51] Using gulpfile ~/hb-productupload/gateway/gulpfile.js
[14:28:51] Starting 'install'...
[14:28:51] Starting 'wiredep:test'...
[14:28:51] Starting 'wiredep:app'...
[14:28:51] Starting 'sso-wiredep'...
[14:28:51] Starting 'ngconstant:dev'...
[14:28:51] 'ngconstant:dev' errored after 54 ms
[14:28:51] Error in plugin 'gulp-tslint-log'
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1326:5)
    at getFilePath (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:95:27)
    at DestroyableTransform.objectStream [as _transform] (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:60:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:352:10)
    at ngConstantPlugin (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:33:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/gulpfile.js:310:16)
    at module.exports (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
[14:28:51] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
    An error occured in task 'ngconstant:dev'.
[14:28:51] Finished 'install' after 71 ms
[14:28:51] Finished 'wiredep:test' after 212 ms
[14:28:51] Finished 'sso-wiredep' after 199 ms
[14:28:51] Finished 'wiredep:app' after 357 ms
```

i ran those commands but i got errors i wrote before:

```
npm install
npm install -g bower (no need if you have installed bower)
bower install
bower prune
bower update
npm install -g gulp (no need if you have installed gulp)
gulp install
```

with sudo , still same

```
caner@vegan:~/hb-productupload/gateway$ sudo gulp install
[sudo] password for caner: 
[16:23:16] Using gulpfile ~/hb-productupload/gateway/gulpfile.js
[16:23:16] Starting 'install'...
[16:23:16] Starting 'wiredep:test'...
[16:23:16] Starting 'wiredep:app'...
[16:23:16] Starting 'sso-wiredep'...
[16:23:16] Starting 'ngconstant:dev'...
[16:23:16] 'ngconstant:dev' errored after 55 ms
[16:23:16] Error in plugin 'gulp-tslint-log'
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1326:5)
    at getFilePath (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:95:27)
    at DestroyableTransform.objectStream [as _transform] (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:60:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:352:10)
    at ngConstantPlugin (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:33:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/gulpfile.js:310:16)
    at module.exports (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/caner/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
[16:23:16] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
    An error occured in task 'ngconstant:dev'.
[16:23:16] Finished 'install' after 73 ms
[16:23:16] Finished 'wiredep:test' after 215 ms
[16:23:16] Finished 'sso-wiredep' after 202 ms
[16:23:16] Finished 'wiredep:app' after 360 ms
```